# How to install and use mongodb with node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, installation

I am very new to MongoDB and node. 
So first of all:

- How can I install MongoDB using the terminal on a Mac computer
- Then how can I connect MongoDB with node?
- How can I create a database in MongoDB using node?

  Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

  ```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;   
  var url = "mongodb://localhost:8080/mydb";
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
  if(err)
  {
    console.log('error');
    throw err;
  }
  else
  {
     console.log('success');
  }
  });
  ```

I tried this code but it shows an error.

This is the error I received:

[image: T]

Comment: have you started the mongodb service ?

Comment: You have to start mongo server in your computer and then only you will able to connect it to the client.

Comment: Default port for mongodb is 27017 so your url should be like mongodb://localhost:8080/mydb

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the MongoDB server first.

Do this:

1. Go to the directory where mongo is installed: i.e.: `<mongodb-install-directory>/bin`
2. Start the server by : `./mongod --dbpath <mongo-data-directory>`

Comment: how can I know where I installed mongoDB

Comment: Thank you I got it.